# Hardware spec for a small business virtual server

Tags: virtualization

I am in charge of specifing a new server for our business I would like to virtualize a few servers to try and reduce cost and simplify backup/disaster recovery, we have less than 20 users and only about 5 of these are heavy network users, and a budget of approx £2500-3000

Our current solution is

- 7+ year old ibm x206 server running Windows 2000SBS
- 5+ year old terastation pro II NAS
- a repurposed desktop pc for firewall

I've not taken any performance measurements from the current server as is very different from what I am aiming for and don't believe it would give me any valid information.

These are the servers I wish to virtualize

- Domain controller/File server - Windows 2012 server
- Email server - Linux (possibly Zimbra)
- Application server (solidworks vault) - Windows 2012 server
- Firewall/Web proxy - pfsense

And this is the hardware I estimate that I require

- HP ML350p Gen8 Tower
- 1 x Xeon E5-2409 2.4Ghz 4core
- 32Gb 1600Mhz Ram
- Windows 2012 server
- RAID controller with cache and backup battery
- 4 x 1Tb SAS NL 6Gbps HD (Raid 10)

Does this sound like a suitable specification? Any advice would be greatfully received.

Comment: Which hypervisor will you be using?

Comment: I think I'm going to use the free version of exsi for better Linux compatibility

Comment: Well, the information I provided below applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good start. I would spec this with Enterprise SAS disks instead of Nearline/Midline SAS. I would also make sure to use the 1GB or 2GB Flash-Backed Cache (FBWC) with the Smart Array P420i controller.

I'd suggest stepping up to an HP ProLiant Base Model (versus Entry), as you'll need to spend too much to bring the server in-line with the right features. Never buy at the bottom of a CPU line.

I think the following setup would work. Add disks, RAM and an additional power supply to the configuration below. *Maybe* add another CPU. You can try with one for the moment, but you'll be happier with two (especially Zimbra).

[image]